# Automatic additivity of multiplicative maps

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, ring-theory

There are results which guarantee that a multiplicative bijection between commutative rings is actually additive (that is, it is a ring isomorphism). For example [this result](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1969-021-03/S0002-9939-1969-0240129-7/S0002-9939-1969-0240129-7.pdf) of Martindale initiated this kind of research.

I am interested in the case where we consider rings of continuous functions. More specifically,

> Let $K$ and $L$ be compact Hausdorff spaces. Suppose that there exists a bijection $p\colon C(K)\to C(L)$ which preserves multiplication. Is $p$ a ring isomorphism?

EDIT: The answer is [no](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0606456.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Indeed the answer is no, and one can give a simpler counterexample than the one in the article you linked to.

Note that the ring $\mathbb{R}$ possesses a continuous multiplicative bijection which is not additive, for example $g(x)=x^3$. Choosing $K=L$, the map $ p \colon C(K) \to C(K) $ which sends a function $f$ to $ gf$ is a multiplicative biyection which is not additive.

Comment: $gf$ does not make sense for a general compact space.

Comment: What do you mean? It is just the composition $g \circ f$, why would it not make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, as already observed, but the existence of such a bijection implies the existence of a ring isomorphism between the respective rings of continuous functions (hence also a homomorphism between the underlying compact spaces). This is a theorem of Milgram.

> A.N. Milgram, [Multiplicative semigroups of continuous functions](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-16/issue-2/Multiplicative-semigroups-of-continuous-functions/10.1215/S0012-7094-49-01638-5.short), Duke Math. J. 16 (1949), 377–383.